# Rails Assets: expected ')' got '}' - Command failed with status (1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, less, asset-pipeline, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have recently started to experience strange behavior with my assets pipeline. I am using Ruby on Rails (3.2.3). Notable libraries I'm using:

```
# From Gemfile
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'therubyracer', :require => 'v8'
gem "less-rails"
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '>= 2.1.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'devise', '~> 2.2.3'        #   Note: Recently upgraded
```

I recently went to compile my assets and am hitting this wall:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby /Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=development RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
expected ')' got '}'
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin...]
```

I have spent the last few hours looking into this issue any trying to find a clue as to where this issue is happening. At this point, my main problem is the feedback / error output I'm getting from rails. With the trace, I'm still looking at a problem that seems to exist within one of my many asset files / directories. Other methods of debugging or file tracking during compilation (maybe a more verbose mode of compilation?) would be great at this point.

My next step is to go through my Git commit log and see what changes to the assets pipeline may have caused this problem.

Comment: I would suggest to check your custom assets for mistyped bracket. I would not be so hard to scan the code in your js and stylesheets.Is the application operates properly in dev mode?

Answer (score 1):

This is error in twitter bootstrap gem. Wrong css syntax. Try to remove it from manifest file application.css and restart assets precompile. If it really bootstrap gem try to use last version